# How to test WinHTTP POST locally

Tags: http, post, winhttprequest

I have a requirement to send some data to a 3rd party listener via POST.  I've written a database trigger to send via WinHTTP but I've never done this before.  How can I set up a POST listener and send to myself?  I'm thinking I could use 127.0.0.1 as the IP but am not sure how to go about it?  Ideally I'd like a browser to wait for the input then write it out.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer myself, thanks to [Henry Cipolla's blog](http://www.henrycipolla.com/blog/2010/10/let-me-dump-your-post-free-http-post-test-server/), he has set up www.posttestserver.com that one can test their POSTs at.